# Why doesn't g++ -O3 change division to multiplication?

Tags: c++, g++

I thought g++ -O3 will change division to multiplication automatically. But accroding to this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

double compute0(int i) {
  double d_2 = i * i; 
  double ret = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    ret += j;
  }
  return ret;
}

double compute1(int i) {
  double d_2 = i * i; 
  double ret = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    ret += j / d_2;
  }
  return ret;
}

double compute2(int i) {
  double d_2 = i * i; 
  double d_2_inv = 1.0 / d_2; 
  double ret = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
    ret += j * d_2_inv;
  }
  return ret;
}

double tik() {
  struct timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
  return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec * 1e-6;
}

int main() {
  {
    double begin = tik();
    double ret = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
      ret += compute0(i);
    double end = tik();
    std::cout << "cost time: " << end - begin << " ret: " << ret << std::endl;
  }
  {
    double begin = tik();
    double ret = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
      ret += compute1(i);
    double end = tik();
    std::cout << "cost time: " << end - begin << " ret: " << ret << std::endl;
  }
  {
    double begin = tik();
    double ret = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
      ret += compute2(i);
    double end = tik();
    std::cout << "cost time: " << end - begin << " ret: " << ret << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the output is :

cost time: 0.105436 ret: 4.95e+13

cost time: 0.453676 ret: 8.17441e+11

cost time: 0.203873 ret: 8.17441e+11

WHY?

Comment: You forgot `-ffast-math`.

Comment: Show your compilation command. Did you enable optimizations by compiling e.g. with `g++ -Wall -O2`? Did you look into the generated assembler code (use `g++ -Wall -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` and look into the generated `.s` file). So **edit your question** to improve it (or delete your question)

Answer (score 1):

Compilers usually try to follow IEEE754. In this standard, division is defined exactly. It means, that for every `a/b`, there is a bit-exact answer. If one modifies this into `a*(1/b)`, result may differ a little bit (you might see this effect, if you print your doubles with 16 significant digits)

Compilers usually have an option to relax this. GCC has -ffast-math, VC has /fp:fast.